# Indexing an item in my array that is 'x' does not return True when asked if that indice == 'x'

Tags: python

```
first='4x2'
second='9x'
self.first = [i + ' ' for i in first]
self.second = [i + ' ' for i in second]    
self.poly = list(chain(self.first, self.second))
if self.poly[1].lower() is 'x' and self.poly[4].lower() is 'x':
    >> Fails here
```

but if i have an array like:

```
array = ['x']
if array[0] is 'x':
```

it passes?

Comment: maybe you should check `if 'x' in item` or `if item.startswith('x')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for comparing strings, and also remove extra spaces, just in case:

```
if self.poly[1].strip().lower() == 'x' and self.poly[4].strip().lower() == 'x':
```

Comment: @beaglecode It fails because your strings `self.poly[1]` and `self.poly[4]` have a space in them, so they would pass comparison with `'x '`. You _do_ need to use the `==` however.

Comment: @ beaglecode As nielsen said, you might have spaces in the string, better to remove them. I updated my answer.